# SSH Key authentication

Tags: ssh-keys

I can't setup SSH key authentication to login without entering a password, and just using the private key. Here is the `sshd_config` file of my VPS.

```
# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 8707
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 768

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
PasswordAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding no
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server


# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

UseDNS no

AllowUsers ashfame
```

I generated the key using `ssh-keygen -t rsa` in `.ssh` folder of my local machine. Then I copied the public key file `id_rsa.pub` by `scp id_rsa.pub ashfame@xx.xxx.xx.xx:`
Then I moved the file to the .ssh folder of my user and renamed it to authorized_keys by `mv id_rsa.pub ~ashfame/.ssh/authorized_keys`

I changed the permissions

```
chown -R ashfame:ashfame ~ashfame/.ssh
chmod 700 ~ashfame/.ssh
chmod 600 ~ashfame/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Now the public key is there, its content matches with the one on the local machine but still when I tries to login it shows "Agent admitted failure to sign using the key." What am I missing?

**Edit:**

Output of `ssh -vvv`

```
    OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to xx.xxx.xx.xx [xx.xxx.xx.xx] port 8707.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/ashfame/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /home/ashfame/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/ashfame/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ashfame/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ashfame/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ashfame/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ashfame/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: put_host_port: [xx.xxx.xx.xx]:8707
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[xx.xxx.xx.xx]:8707" from file "/home/ashfame/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/ashfame/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
d    ebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 129/256
debug2: bits set: 517/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA d8:91:1b:8a:90:96:60:27:3b:6e:ae:fc:f2:08:84:f6
debug3: put_host_port: [xx.xxx.xx.xx]:8707
debug3: put_host_port: [xx.xxx.xx.xx]:8707
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[xx.xxx.xx.xx]:8707" from file "/home/ashfame/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/ashfame/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[xx.xxx.xx.xx]:8707" from file "/home/ashfame/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/ashfame/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host '[xx.xxx.xx.xx]:8707' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ashfame/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 514/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/ashfame/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f5e60674670)
debug2: key: /home/ashfame/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/ashfame/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/ashfame/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp 40:16:89:d5:e3:38:cc:84:7a:1e:44:d6:84:5a:87:86
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA 40:16:89:d5:e3:38:cc:84:7a:1e:44:d6:84:5a:87:86
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ashfame/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/ashfame/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ashfame/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/ashfame/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Comment: output of ssh -vvv?

Comment: @rogerdpack Added in the question, please take a look

Comment: @ashfame - I think he was asking you to add "-vvv" to your regular ssh command.  Without a connection there's nothing for `ssh` to be verbose about...

Comment: @voretaq7 Oops! I added the output. I think there is a mismatch somehow. I am using both RSA & DSA somehow. Not sure how I ended up with using both.

Comment: I'm not sure how openssh selects keys off the top of my head - I usually use `ssh-agent` or manually tell ssh which key to present (`-i`).  You may want to try the latter while debugging.  Also see the update to my answer: I can replicate the behavior you're seeing if my key isn't in the `authorized_keys` file so something may have gotten SNAFU'd with your 2 keys...

Comment: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN' seems a bit odd maybe run dos2unix on the file, or regenerate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today when I switched on my machine, I could login without the need of a password. I guess tha was just a temporary glitch. Else @voretaq7 answer would have been better in helping. I am accepting my answer and upvoting his answer.

Answer (score 9):

`Agent admitted failure to sign using the key` is often OpenSSH speak for "You're running `ssh-agent` on the client and forgot to `ssh-add` the key you want to use."

Try running `ssh-add` on the client machine and see if your error goes away.  You may need to consult the [`ssh-add` manpage](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/ssh-add/) for additional parameters to pass to `ssh-add`, particularly if your private key is named something non-standard...

---

Edit based on new info in the question from `ssh -vvv`:

```
debug3: Could not load "/home/ashfame/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
```

Looks like your keyfile is malformed somehow.  Triple-check to make sure something hasn't been corrupted there (extra/missing stuff).
I also got the same message when the public key wasn't in `authorized_keys` on the server side, which may just be OpenSSH being lousy about informative error messages -- something else to double check though.

Comment: I have the standard names only `id_rsa` & `id_rsa.pub`. Do I still need to do anything with `ssh-add`?

Answer (score 0):

To bypass the agent, try this:

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=0 ssh user@host
```